# Replacement for Spring Methods Upgrade

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, upgrade

We  are upgrading our application from Spring 1.2.6 to Spring 4.0.3. We are looking for replacement for below methods. Please help us if you know the solution.

`AbstractWizardFormController`:

- `String[] getPages()` - Return the wizard pages, i.e. the view names for the pages.
- `protected  int getCurrentPage(HttpServletRequest request)` - Return the current page number.

`AbstractFormController`:

- `boolean isSessionForm()` - Return true if session form mode is activated.
- `boolean isFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request)` - Determine if the given request represents a form submission.
- `protected String getFormSessionAttributeName()` - Return the name of the `PortletSession` attribute that holds the form object for this form controller.

Comment: Have you noticed that `AbstractWizardFormController` and `AbstractFormController` have been deprecated as of Spring 3.0 and removed from Spring 4.0 completely, right?

Comment: yes I am aware of it...so few methods whatever I listed shows error now and I am looking replacement for thoses methods do you have any idea ? It would be great help.

Comment: This might become an extensive operation, you might need to redesign your classes, Spring docs mentions those were deprecated in favor of annotation based configuration.